# Employer refusing to discuss severance until resignation letter received

Tags: ethics, resignation, ireland

(This doesn't apply to me) 
(Ireland)

Employee is 64 with 1 year left to retirement, working for the company for 17 years.

Employer has verbally offered 2 months pay in return for employees resignation letter, or the other option was employee would be placed on a PIP (Performance Improvement Plan) with the possibility of being fired and receive nothing.

This situation arose because of instances of (doctor certified) sick leave above what the company decided was acceptable.

Employee asked for (written) confirmation of offer, but employer declined and said the offer would be discussed after receipt of resignation letter.

Employee is willing to accept x months pay, but the company will not confirm this before resignation, which would really leave employee without a leg to stand on.
Employee feels the atmosphere will be toxic if decides to go back to work on a PIP and ideally would like to avoid that.

What is the best way to approach this situation?

Comment: I don't see how we can help.   It a decision he needs to make.  VTC

Comment: This is a legal matter, and out of scope of the workplace, so we cannot tell you to find an employment lawyer who specializes in the discrimination towards disabilities and age.  I'm sorry we can't help

Comment: @RutherRendommeleigh PIP stands for Performance Improvement Program.  Which is almost always just an exercise in building a file for termination

Comment: If I were the employee I would not resign in this situation without something in writing....

Comment: Well, your  friend could just put, in their resignation letter, the terms that were discussed.

"I am submitting my resignation on the condition that I receive Z months resignation pay, as discussed with X on Someday, A/B/2018 at 2pm."

But given all the factors you mention, Ricard U is correct - an employment lawyer is worthwhile

Comment: The obvious answer is that if you give a letter of resignation then they can simply accept it and give you nothing. That is what they are probably trying to make you do - or at least put you in a position where you have to accept their terms because you have already resigned.

Comment: @RichardU Except this isn't USA, it's Ireland. Ireland doesn't do fire at will, so would be more difficult to fire somebody without strong evidence. a PIP in Ireland has a very different meaning than one in the US

Comment: @Draken My comment was not USA specific, and from the people I know in the UK and Ireland, there isn't that much difference in what a PIP is.  And it's "at will", not "fire at will".  Employees in the US don't have to give notice when they leave either.

Comment: Sign nothing, keep working, and document everything extremely thoroughly. Slam-dunk case for employment tribunal if they follow through with PIP and dismissal.